# Good approach for conditionally setting CSS class mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I know I can use HtmlHelpers which will access data repository and return the appropriate class.

```
<a class="<%= Html.GetOnOffState(); %>"...
```

But what other approaches are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write an entire actionlink helper so that instead of the following tag soup:

```
<a class="<%= Html.GetOnOffState(); %>"..
```

you would use:

```
<%= Html.ToggableActionLink("foo", "bar") %>
```